# Convert speed: m/s to km/h

Tags: objective-c

I am new to Objective-C and would like some help with converting MPS to KPH.

Below is my current string for speed. Can someone please point out what else is needed?

```
speed.text = newLocation.speed < 0 ? @"N/A": [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", (int)newLocation.speed];
```

Comment: If you are new at programming (reading your question, it seems to be), I would not use the "()?," system to do an if...
I'd do it slowly...
Creating an int to get the converted speed, then putting in the label...

Answer (score 5):

m/s to km/h = (m/s) * (60*60)/1000

Or 1m/s = 3.6km/h

```
float speedInKilometersPerHour = newLocation.speed*3.6;
if (speedInKilometersPerHour!=0) {speed.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", speedInKilometersPerHour];}
else speed.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"No Data Available"];
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way to do it (I've formatted it to be a little more readable):

```
if (newLocation.speed < 0)
    speed.text = @"N/A";
else
    speed.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", (int)(newLocation.speed * 3.6)];
```

Note however, that you really should be using a number formatter to convert the number to a localized string before displaying it to the user so that it is formatted correctly in their own locale:

```
if (newLocation.speed < 0)
{
    speed.text = @"N/A";
} 
else
{
    int speedKPH                    = (int)(newLocation.speed * 3.6);
    NSNumber *number                = [NSNumber numberWithInt:speedKPH];

    NSNumberFormatter *formatter    = [NSNumberFormatter new];
    formatter.numberStyle           = NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle;

    speed.text                      = [formatter stringFromNumber:number];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you mean Meters Per Second to Kilometers Per Hour, and you want us to modify your existing ternary, than this would do the job.

```
speed.text = (newLocation.speed < 0) ? (@"N/A") : ([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", (int)(newLocation.speed*3.6)]);
```

If the original speed in MPS was less than zero, than its not applicable, otherwise it converts it.

You should also probably round the result to the nearest integer, so that it's more accurate.

```
speed.text = (newLocation.speed < 0) ? (@"N/A") : ([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", (int)((newLocation.speed*3.6)+0.5)]);
```

Comment: How does that always round up? You add 0.5 and and use `floor` to get the largest integer that is not larger than the argument. 3.4 would become 3.9, floor would leave it at 3. 3.6 would become 4.1, floor would leave it at 4. It rounds nearest, unless I missed something. floor(1.01 + 0.5) = 1, right?

Comment: Yes, you are right.  I didn't look at the code, just your comment where you said "You should also probably round up."  :)  My apologies....  You should probably change that to say "You should also probably round the speed" or something.

Comment: Oh, yes. I'll edit that! That's valid. Also... why am I using `floor` again? The integer cast truncates towards zero, anyways. `floor` trends towards negative infinity, IIRC, and we've already weeded out the negatives meaning there's no difference... editing.

Comment: Oh, and one more minor thing.  0 is a valid speed, so I don't see any reason to check for that after the conversion.  He is simply checking to make sure that it is not **less** than 0 before the conversion is done.

Comment: Yes, I thought about that, but figured that some people might want to do something if they got zero since it's misleading. A rounded value may be slightly off, but the difference between no speed and some speed is a bigger difference. I'll edit it out.